# accessing flash drive in python

Tags: python

Dear friends i am trying to access the flash drive when i select option 2 on the menu list, however i always get an error. could someone help me please.i am getting directories that are not the f: drive which is where the flash drive is installed. Your support will be highly appreciated

```
    #This is tutorial on operating system managers
#====================================================
#MENU FUNCTIONS
 #====================================================

def print_menu(): 
    print('Welcome,here is a briefly operating system management tutorial:')

    #begin of choices

    print('1. Process Management')
    print('2. File Management')
    print('3. Device Management')
    print('4. Memory Management')
    print('5. Back')
    print('6. Exit')
    print()

    numbers={}
    menu_choices=0
    print_menu()



    while menu_choices !=6:

    menu_choices=int(input("Type in a number between (1-6):"))

    if menu_choices==1:
        print ("Process Management:")
        print (">>")
        print (">>")
        print()

    elif menu_choices==2:
        import os
        print("File Management")
        print(" Insert a USB in a disk F: ")
        print( os.listdir('/'))


    elif menu_choices==3:  
        print("Device Management")
        print (" >> ")
        print (" >> ")
        print()

    elif menu_choices==4:
        print("Memory Management")
        print(" >> ")
        print(" >> ")
        print()

    elif menu_choices==5:
        print_menu()  


    elif menu_choices==6:
         print("Goodbye")    
         print()    


    else:
        menu_choices !=""
        print ('Invalid selection, please try again.')
        print_menu()
        print()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't change to the F: drive first, `os.listdir` will just list files on the current drive.

`os.chdir('F:')`

Comment: or just specify it in the listdir, as `os.listdir("F:\\")`